# Hirsch, Smale ODE book: Ch.8 ex 10

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is:

Let $g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Lipschitz and $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous. Show that the system
$$x'=g(x)$$
$$y'=f(x)y$$
has at most one solution on any interval, for a given initial value. (Hint: use
Gronwall's inequality.)

My question is: isn't this immediate from the existence-uniqueness theory? Why they ask to use Gronwall? Specifically, for given initial values $x(0),y(0)$, and a fixed interval $I$ (containing zero), the first ODE has at most one solution (it might have none if $I$ is large). Now, if it has a solution, then the unique solution of the second ODE is $y(t)=e^{\int_{0}^t f(x(u))du}$.

Comment: Yes, you’re right. By uniqueness, the solution of $x’=g(x)$ is unique given the initial value $x(0)$, and thus the second equation has a unique solution, too. On the other hand, the uniqueness of solutions of $x’=g(x)$ can be proved using Gronwall’s inequality, without using Picard’s theorem, and the authors may want readers to be more familiar with the “Gronwall$\to$ uniqueness” approach, which will be very helpful in the future study. I recommend you to try yourself the Gronwall approach.